# How to perform a major reorganization of subversion repository

Tags: svn

I have inherited management of a subversion repository for a group of people, which is incredibly poorly organized the directory structure is something like this:

```
/root
    /branches
        /branch_1_with_cryptic_name
        /branch_2_with_different_cryptic_name
        /branch_3_with_super_cryptic_name
        ...
        /branch_N_with_another_cryptic_name
    /tags
        /tag_1_with_yet_another_cryptic_name
        /tag_2_with_another_different_cryptic_name
        ...
        /tag_M_with_some_other_cryptic_name
    /trunk
        /project_1
        /project_2
        ...
        /project_K
```

notice that the branches and tags are not organized with respect to their respective projects, so it is impossible to tell which branch/tag goes with which project, unless you are familiar with it already.

I would like to re-organize the directory structure in the following way

```
/root
    /project_1
        /branches
            /branch_1_with_some_name
            /but_at_least_i_know_which_project
        /tags
            /some_tag_1
            /some_tag_2
        /trunk
    /project_2
        /branches
        /tags
        /trunk
    ...
    /project_K
        /branches
        /tags
        /trunk
```

Additionally, I would like to maintain the history of each file, and allow switching/merging between the existing branches and trunk of each project.

I am using tortoise SVN, and have tried simply moving the directories around in the repo-browser, but switching only works if I "ignore ancestry", and merging results in every file having a tree-conflict.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the full repo on your machine (trunk + branches + tags) you can move them around using Tortoise SVN. It's just not very obvious (I know I had to look hard).

Select the folder(s) and Copy or Cut them with Ctrl-C/Ctrl-X or Context Menu->Copy/Cut as usual. Go to the destination folder and then **right click for Context Menu -> TortoiseSVN -> Paste**. Don't you DARE using regular Paste (but I'm sure you're aware of that).

Alternative method : select the folder(s) to move around and move them like you would with any file by **right-clicking** on them. On releasing the right mouse button, select SVN Move/Copy versioned files here.

This should move your folders around safely, preserving version history. I *think* you can do the same using the Repo Browser but I haven't used it much.

I hope this works for you!

[Source](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd forget about switching and use plain ol' `svn move`, `svn rm`, `svn mkdir` to achieve the desired structure. Since these commands keep track of the history of all files, you *should* be able to merge folders that were mergeable before.

One possible course of action could be the following:

1. Create `project_1`, `project_2` etc. using `svn mkdir`
2. In each project directory, create the `tags` and `branches` directories
3. Move the original project directories into their new location in `trunk/`
4. Move the original branches into their respective new locations in `project_x/branches/`
5. Move the original tags into their respective new locations in `project_x/tags/`